# How do I capture the color value of a Google Charts pie charts slice?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I've got a working example of how to make a pie chart interact with a table. What I'd like to add is a visual cue of their correlation. The only examples I've seen are where the table row is highlighted by [adding a listener](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#interaction_using_events). I'd like to add an empty cell within the table who's background color is the color of the pie slice it corresponds to. How do I capture the color of the pie slice? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hoyasultan/r66vw/)

What I have now:

```
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart","table"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawProductAllocationChart);
  function drawProductAllocationChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Name', 'Allocation'],
      ['Product A', 25],
      ['Product B', 50],
      ['Product C', 15],
      ['Product D', 10]
    ]);

    var options = {
      //title: 'My Daily Activities'
      is3D: true
    };

    var productAllocationChart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('product-allocation-chart'));
    productAllocationChart.draw(data, options);

    var productAllocationTable = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('product-allocation-table'));
    productAllocationTable.draw(data, null);

    // When the table is selected, update the orgchart.
    google.visualization.events.addListener(productAllocationTable, 'select', function() {
      portfolioAllocationChart.setSelection(productAllocationTable.getSelection());
    });

    // When the orgchart is selected, update the table visualization.
    google.visualization.events.addListener(productAllocationChart, 'select', function() {
      productAllocationTable.setSelection(productAllocationChart.getSelection());
    });
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there an option to set the background color for a cell? I didn't see it in the docs, but it was just a quick look.

Comment: @hoyasultan. I believe the following answer solve your problem. Can you mark it as answered?

Answer (score 4):

My first thought is to just create a map of the default colors for Google Charts. Although, I haven't used the data tables for the visualization api yet.

From the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/ePpJQEeUX8M) I got this list of 31 default colors:

```
["#3366cc","#dc3912","#ff9900","#109618","#990099","#0099c6","#dd4477","#66aa00","#b82e2e","#316395","#994499","#22aa99","#aaaa11","#6633cc","#e67300","#8b0707","#651067","#329262","#5574a6","#3b3eac","#b77322","#16d620","#b91383","#f4359e","#9c5935","#a9c413","#2a778d","#668d1c","#bea413","#0c5922","#743411"]
```

I assume you know the order that things are being added to the pie chart, and it most likely corresponds to the order of rows within the table. If that's the case, then just map the array to the row.

Comment: Been away for a few days, thanks @EnigmaRM, I'm going to give that a shot

Comment: I haven't used the visualization for the tables. Can you set the background color of a cell?

Comment: @Jonas T, you may want to take a closer look... I didn't ask the question. I'm the one that supplied the answer to the question. The person who asked the question must mark it as the correct answer...